# java rmi re-connecting client problem

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to develop a simple server/client program usrin java rmi. everything seems to work fine so far, but the only problem is that when a client exits and tries to reconnect i get the following exception:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.x.y; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

why does the server refused connection the second time?

here is my code

server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Naming.rebind("ChatServer", new ChatServerImpl());

        Naming.rebind("NotificationSource",  nsource);

        System.out.println("Chat Server is up and runnning!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Problem!!!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the "Chat Server" and "nsource" (which nsource is static) are UnicastRemoteObject objects that extend "Remote" Intefaces. ("ChatServer" , and "NotificationInterface").

client

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String url_ChatServer = "rmi://localhost/ChatServer";
    String url_NotificationSource = "rmi://localhost/NotificationSource";

    try {

        ChatServer cs = (ChatServer) Naming.lookup(url_ChatServer);

        NotificationSourceInterface ns = (NotificationSourceInterface) Naming.lookup(url_NotificationSource);

        new Thread(new ChatClientImpl(cs,ns)).start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Problem ~Client");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

i am not using rmic since it is not longer required (since java 1.5)

thx

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting that on the lookup, the Registry is down. If you get it calling the remote method, its JVM has exited.